# How to remove the y-axis, keep the x-axis and align the x-ticks and labels on the plot, and add the y-values in a Tikz/pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to recreate the following stem plots in Tikz/pgfplots. 
So far I was able to do the following. I want to be able to control the elements of the figure window. For this particular case: remove the y-axis labels and ticks, rotate the y-label 90 degrees {x(n)} and position somewhere else, retain the x-axis labels and ticks and align them with the plot, and add the y-values in the plots.

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usetheme{Boadilla}
 \usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Using PGF Plots}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

   \begin{axis}[
   every outer y axis line/.style={draw=none}, 
   tick  style={draw=none}, 
   xlabel=n,ylabel=x(n),
   % this will put the y-values
   nodes near coords,
   point meta = y
   ]

    \addplot[ycomb,color=blue,mark=o, very thick] coordinates {
    (-3,0) (-2,4) (-1,0) (0,2) (1,0) (2,0) (3,-1)
    };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just learned from PGFPlots Gallery (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) that the following commands will add the y-values         [nodes near coords, 
        point meta = y], but how to remove the zeros? Since they are not important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This makes it rather similar. To get rid of the y axis we use

```
axis y line=left,
y axis line style={opacity=0},
ytick=\empty,
```

To get rid of unwanted ticks and nodes, comparisons are employed. And there are a couple of further changes (see code). (I would have thought that I would not need to recycle `\pgfmathparseFPU` here but maybe I am missing something.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
 \pgfmathparse{#1}%
 \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Using PGF Plots}
\begin{tikzpicture}

   \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,
   x axis line style={thick},
   enlarge x limits,
   axis y line=left,
   y axis line style={opacity=0},ytick=\empty,
   xticklabel=\ifdim\tick pt<3pt $\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\fi,
   tick  style={draw=none}, 
   xlabel=$n$,ylabel=$x(n)$,
   nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
   \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
   nodes near coords align=left,
   point meta = y
   ]

    \addplot[ycomb,color=blue,mark=*, very thick] coordinates {
    (-3,0) (-2,4) (-1,0) (0,2) (1,0) (2,0) (3,-1)
    };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely getting closer to what I imagined it would look like.

Comment: But the last y-value {-1} at n=3 was not displayed, any ideas?

Comment: @Rhandley Good catch! Fixed.